# Regex that finds groups of lines where certain lines within the group starting with a certain string occur more than once

Tags: python, regex, search, line

I have a file that has multiple lines. I need a regex that finds all of the groups that contain multiple occurrences of a particular string.
If the file has:

> START 
> MIDDLE 
>  RANDOM 
> MIDDLE 
> END 
> START 
> MIDDLE 
>  RANDOM 
> END
>
> START 
> MIDDLE 
>  RANDOM 
> MIDDLE 
> END

I would like the regex to only match the lines in bold as separate groups where MIDDLE occurs more than once:

> **START 
> MIDDLE 
>  RANDOM 
> MIDDLE 
> END** 
> START 
> MIDDLE 
>  RANDOM 
> END
>
> **START 
> MIDDLE 
>  RANDOM 
> MIDDLE 
> END**

What I have tried is this and several variations but its not matching the groups I need.

```
(START(?:\nMIDDLE){2,}(?:\nMIDDLE)*\nEND)
(START\*STUFF~(?:\nMIDDLE\*STUFF~){2,}(?:\nMIDDLE\*STUFF~)*\nEND\*STUFF~)
```

Comment: And you, obviously, don't want START or END to be inside your groups wore than once. Right?

Comment: Something like this: https://regex101.com/r/Cvc0Z8/1 ?

Comment: Or shorter: https://regex101.com/r/Cvc0Z8/3

Comment: Wow.. that is what I needed. Matches only the groups that have MIDDLE more than once given group borders of START/END. Thank you!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I see our regular expressions are quite similar. Where you have  `(?!MIDDLE|END)` I have `(?!END\n)` in part to permit `'ENDLESS'`, but I'm wondering if you excluded `'MIDDLE'` for reasons of efficiency (as it does not seem to be necessary). Note also that you are allowing lines containing `'STARTLED'` and `'ENDLESS'` to bracket the lines of interest.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: yes, I indeed chose to use greedy quantifiers, that's why I excluded "MIDDLE" in the lookaheads because the subject string in the question is only an example and I don't know how look the strings in real life. For the same reason I didn't put any word-boundary or line-feed after the words. These patterns are more intended to illustrate an idea and then be adapted to strings probably written in Klingon.

Answer (score 1):

Use two expressions:

```
import re

data = """
START
MIDDLE
RANDOM
MIDDLE
END
START
MIDDLE
RANDOM
END
START
MIDDLE
RANDOM
MIDDLE
END
"""

rx_block = re.compile(r'^START.+?^END', re.M | re.S)
rx_inner = re.compile(r'MIDDLE')

for block in rx_block.finditer(data):
    occurences = rx_inner.findall(block.group(0))
    if len(occurences) > 1:
        print(block.group(0))
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/9DgyJa).

Answer (score 1):

You can match the regular expression

```
^START\n(?:(?:(?!END\n).*\n)*MIDDLE\n){2}(?:.*\n)*?END$
```

with `RE.M`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P4sKBY/11)

---

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^           # match beginning of a line
START\n     # match literal then line terminator
(?:         # begin a non-capture group
  (?:       # begin a non-capture group
    (?!     # begin a negative lookahead
      END   # match literal
      \n    # match line terminator
    )       # end negative lookahead
    .*      # match zero or more characters other than line terminators
    \n      # match line terminator
  )         # end non-capture group
  *         # execute preceding non-capture group zero or more times
  MIDDLE\n  # match literal then line terminator
){2}        # end non-capture group, execute it twice 
(?:         # begin a non-capture group
  .*\n      # match zero or more characters then line terminator
)           # end non-capture group
*?          # execute the preceding non-capture group zero or more times,
            # as few times as possible (lazily) 
END$        # match literal at end of line
```

If it may be necessary to match strings produced with Windows (which uses `"\r\n"` as its line terminator) change each instance of `\n` in the regular expression to `\r?\n`.

---

Note that the amount of backtracking can be reduced by changing

```
(?:(?!END\n)
```

to the *greedy quantifier*

```
(?:(?!(?:END|MIDDLE)\n)
```

Compare the numbers of steps and execution time for [`(?:(?!END\n)`](https://regex101.com/r/JOFSce/1) (703 steps, 0.8ms) with those measures for [`(?:(?!(?:END|MIDDLE)\n)`](https://regex101.com/r/7Sk3yE/1) (511 steps, 0.2ms).

Comment: Why using `(?1)` when you can simply repeat the whole group with a quantifier `{2}` ? (Note that with this change you don't even need to use the pypi/regex package, re suffices.)

Comment: Note that `^` are redundant in `\n(?:^` since they follow a line feed.

Comment: I wish to thank @CasimiretHippolyte for his suggestions which I have incorporated in an edit to my original answer. In fact my answer is effectively what he suggested in two comments on the question.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, many thanks. In your comments on the question you have `...(?!END).*\n)*END...`, whereas I have `...(?:.*\n)*?END...`. Again, were you motivated there by efficiency considerations?

Comment: I tend to often prefer greedy quantifiers and therefore write this kind of thing rather than using a non-greedy quantifier. And that's not always a good idea! See and compare: https://regex101.com/r/NdyCTN/1 with https://regex101.com/r/NdyCTN/2

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, that's interesting and thanks for reminding me of regex101's counting of steps and execution time, which I should look at more often.